# How to make JAXB Marshaller marshal abstract class based on its runtime type?

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

Consider the following abstract class -

```
public abstract class Car
{
    public abstract void drive(double miles);
}
```

Here's a sample class (for illustration purposes) that extends the above class.

```
public class Ferrari extends Car
{
    private String lastUsed; // Ferrari specific field not in Car
    private boolean f1Car;   // Ferrari specific field not in Car

    @XmlElement
    public void setF1Car(boolean f1Car)
    {
        this.f1Car = f1Car;
    }

    public boolean isF1Car() { return f1Car; }

    @XmlElement
    public void setLastUsed(String lastUsed)
    {
        this.lastUsed = lastUsed;
    }

    public String getLastUsed() { return lastUsed; }

    public void drive(double miles)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

I have a report class that contains a Car object -

```
@XmlRootElement
public class CarTestReport
{
    private String date;
    private double miles;
    private Car car;

    @XmlElement
    public void setDate(String date) { this.date = date;}

    public String getDate() {return date;}

    @XmlElement
    public void setMiles(double miles) { this.miles = miles; }

    public double getMiles() {return miles;}

    @XmlElement
    public void setCar(Car car) { this.car = car; }

    public Car getCar() { return car; }
}
```

And here is the piece of code using JAXB to Marshall a CarTestReport object -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Ferrari ferrari = new Ferrari();
    ferrari.setLastUsed("July 5 2012");
    ferrari.setF1Car(false);

    CarTestReport  report = new CarTestReport();
    report.setDate("July 6 2012");
    report.setMiles(200);
    report.setCar(ferrari);

    File file = new File("carTestReport.xml");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CarTestReport.class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(report, file);
}
```

The problem is, because of the abstract type Car, JAXB ignores it and doesn't marshall the Ferrari object when it marshals the CarTestReport object. The output I get is this -

```
<carTestReport>
  <car/>
  <date>July 6 2012</date>
  <miles>200.0</miles>
</carTestReport>
```

As you can see, nothing was entered under the 'car' node, even though the Ferrari object was populated. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The JAXB system doesn't look through the classpath for any possible JAXB-annotated classes.  You have to help it find them.  In your sample code, it simply doesn't know about the existence of the `Ferrari` class.  (It only sees `Car` because that's the return type of the getter in `CarTestReport`.)

One quick and dirty way to tell JAXB about `Ferrari` is to add `@XmlSeeAlso({Ferrari.class})` at the top of your `Car` class.  Then you'll get output like this:

```
<carTestReport>
  <car xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ferrari">
    <f1Car>false</f1Car>
    <lastUsed>July 5 2012</lastUsed>
  </car>
  <date>July 6 2012</date>
  <miles>200.0</miles>
</carTestReport>
```

Another way to tell JAXB about `Ferrari` would be to pass that class to the `JAXBContext.newInstance` method, i.e.:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CarTestReport.class,
        Ferrari.class);
```

Or if all of your JAXB classes are in the same package, e.g. `com.mycompany.carstuff`, then you could do this:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.mycompany.carstuff");
```

And in this last case it WILL search for all classes in that package.

If you want it to emit an element named `ferrari` (instead of the `<car xsi:type="ferrari">` like above), one possibility is to add `@XmlType` to the top of your `Car` class, like this:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlSeeAlso({Ferrari.class})
@XmlType
public abstract class Car {
  public abstract void drive(double miles);
}
```

...and put `@XmlRootElement` on `Ferrari`, e.g.:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Ferrari extends Car {
  // ...
}
```

From what I understand, this combination of annotations tells JAXB that the `Car` class maps to an XML schema *type* (so you won't get any elements named "car"), and that the `Ferrari` class is an *element* of that type (so you *can* have elements named "ferrari").  And the "root" in `@XmlRootElement` is misleading... it can be an element anywhere in the structure of your objects.

Comment: Why to put XmlRootElement on Ferrari?

Comment: `@XmlRootElement` says that the `Ferrari` Java class should correspond to a named XML element.  (And the `@XmlType` on `Car` says that "Car" is a type name, not an element name.  So we won't ever get a `<car>` element.)  The "root" is misleading, since it can be an element anywhere in the structure.

Comment: @csd what should you do if you don't know the name of the class (i.e. `Ferrari`) but you still want to emit an element called with the name of that class? Imagine the same example, but you have a collection of cars without knowning the exact name?

Answer (score 2):

You need to annotate your Ferrari class with `@XmlRootElement` and replace `@XmlElement` on the car attribute with `@XmlElementRef`